# How does this proof show that this conjugate group is a subgroup of $\pi_1(X, x_1)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, covering-spaces

I'm self learning Rotman's Algebraic Topology and I've come across the proof in the below picture.

I don't understand how the proof shows that $S=p_*\pi_1(\tilde X, \tilde x_1)$.  The proof initially starts with conjugate groups and then uses the commutative diagram to show the equality.  But I don't understand what the link is here between the graphs being conjugate and the commutativity of the diagram.

It seems like it skips a step relating the two.  It constructs a path in $\tilde X$ from $\tilde x_0$ to $\tilde x_1$ and then immediately starts the line $S = \dots$

**What is the link between the constructed path, the conjugate groups, and the commutative diagram?**  (The figure at the bottom of the image is the diagram used in the proof)

[image]

Comment: Well, I think that $\sigma(x)=[\lambda^{-1}]x[\lambda]$ is the canonical isomorphism and since $S=[\lambda^{-1}]H[\lambda]$ then $S=\sigma(H)$. That's where the first equality "$S=\ldots$" comes from. The second one comes from the commutative diagram (it would be easier if we knew what Theorem 10.10 says) since $\sigma p_{*}=p_{*}\Sigma$.

Answer (score 0):

I feel this a good example where one uses the **algebraic model** of a covering map in terms of a **covering morphism** $q: H \to G$ of groupoids.

Certainly if $p: \widetilde{X} \to X$ is a covering map of spaces then the induced morphism $\pi_1(p)$ of fundamental groupoids is a covering morphism. The definition of covering morphism $q: H \to G$ is that if $y \in Ob(H)$ and $g: p(y) \to x $ in $G$ then there is a unique $h: y \to z$ in $H$ such that 
$q(h) = g$.

The full details are in Chapter 10 of [Topology and Groupoids](http://groupoids.org.uk/topgpdws.html), (T&G, downloadable),  as they were in previous differently titled editions (1968, 1988). Peter May's "Concise ..." book also has some information on covering morphisms of groupoids. The simplification of notation,  replacing $\pi_1(X,x)$ by the object group $G(x)$, should also make it easier to write down the necessary arguments.

The relation of covering morphisms to actions of groupoids on sets is given in this [stackexchange answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61772/classi%EF%AC%81cation-of-covering-spaces/155646#155646), and also in T&G. The notion of covering morphism of groupoids is also a special case of the useful notion of **fibration of groupoids**.